# Image flipper not reflowing height

Tags: html, css, magento-1.9

not sure how to search for this, so have started a question from scratch.

I have a block of four images in a row which flip over to an info pane on hover, with a link to the item. This flows down to two images by two images on mobile and tablet sites.

I'm really happy with the look and effect at full desktop size, however the images run over the remaining content on the page (and the second row of images on mobile) unless I specify a fixed height for '.flip-container'. If I have a fixed height however, this means that the whole block doesn't reflow properly (and I still get some overlapping).

Therefore - my main question, is how do I make the height of '.flip-container' responsive to its contents? This is running as a static block in Magento.

An additional problem I have come across is that this really doesn't work well in Safari (though it is ok in all other browsers I have tried). Essentially, the reverse side of the image is still showing, as is the drop shadow of the info pane. Any suggestions appreciated.

Probably easier for the code/example explain itself...

All help much appreciated. If anyone needs any further details, let me know

Live example (it's the second content block within the page with four book covers): http://bit.ly/1Mz2nQ0

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="featured">
<div class="flip-left">
    <div class="flip-container first-flip" style="margin-left: 0px;">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front"><img alt="Book Title, Author Name" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/HOME/featured/9781785300080.jpg"}}" /></div>
            <div class="back">
                <h3>Book Title</h3>
                <h4>Author Name</h4>
                <h4>&pound;7.99</h4>
                <div class="read-more"><a href="../book-url.html"> <button type="button">Read More</button></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front"><img alt="Book Title, Author Name" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/HOME/featured/9781845029951.jpg"}}" /></div>
            <div class="back">
                <h3>Book Title</h3>
                <h4>Author Name</h4>
                <h4>&pound;7.99</h4>
                <div class="read-more"><a href="../book-url.html"> <button type="button">Read More</button></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-right">
<div class="flip-container first-flip">
     <div class="flipper">
         <div class="front"><img alt="Book Title, Author Name" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/HOME/featured/9781845029890.jpg"}}" /></div>
         <div class="back">
             <h3>Book Title</h3>
                <h4>Author Name</h4>
                <h4>&pound;7.99</h4>
                <div class="read-more"><a href="../book-url.html"> <button type="button">Read More</button></a></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container" style="margin-right: 0px;">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"><img alt="Book Title, Author Name" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/HOME/featured/9781845029852.jpg"}}" /></div>
        <div class="back">
            <h3>Book Title</h3>
                <h4>Author Name</h4>
                <h4>&pound;7.99</h4>
                <div class="read-more"><a href="../book-url.html"> <button type="button">Read More</button></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 * ============================================ *
 * Image Flipper 4-column
 * ============================================ */

.featured {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-size:0;
    }

.featured .flip-container img {

    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    }

.flip-left {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    }

.flip-right {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    }

.flip-container {
    width: 45.3125%;
    height: 334px;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 3.125%;
    margin-left: 3.125%
    }

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    }
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.back {
    width: 100%;
    }

.front {
    width:100%;
    }

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

   position: relative;
   }

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: $c-dark-grey;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    }

/* Text Styles */

.featured .flipper .back {
    h3 {
        color: white;
       }

    h4 {
        color: $c-gray;
        }
    }

.read-more button {
    max-width: 90%;
    background: $c-button;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    }

.read-more button:hover {
    background: $c-button-hover;
    }

/* Media Breakpoint */
@include bp(max-width, $bp-medium) {

    .featured {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        }

    .flip-container {
        width: 46.875%;     
        margin: 0 0 0 0px;
        }

    .flip-left .first-flip {
        margin-right: 6.25%;
        }

    .flip-right .first-flip {
        margin-right: 6.25%;
        }


    .flip-left {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        }

    .flip-right {
        width:100%;
        float: none;

        .first {
            margin-left:0px;
            }

        }
    }

.team-wall .flip-right {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid you have to specify a fixed height to `.flip-container` because the `.front` and `.back` has `position:absolute` so the wrapper - `.flipper`, don't "save" a place for them. You can fix it by `javascript` (If you must), I can help you with this. Which version and OS do you use with the `Safari`?

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks, that makes a (little) more sense. When I remove the position:absolute on .front and .back, and remove the height from .flip-container, the whole lot is reflowable, but only with .back below .front (making a combined height). Therefore, I will need to use Javascript to mimic the effect of 'position: absolute' so that .back will appear behind .front? Any help or pointers much apprecitated, as I don't have much experience with Javascript. Safari version is Version 9.0.1 (10601.2.7.2), on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. I'll add some screenshots to the main post if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in JavaScript using jQuery.

Flip effect source: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

```js
$('.flipper').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this),
      front = elem.find('.front');
  
  elem.height(front.height());
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
}
 /* flip the pane when hovered */
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container/*, .front, .back*/ {
 width: 250px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
  
    width:100%;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #a4a4a4;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    height:100%; /* now, you can set this to 100%, because his parent - .flipper - has height*/
}

img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
   <img alt="Ursula's Secret, Mairi Wilson" src="http://testsite.itchycoo-education.com/media/wysiwyg/HOME/featured/9781785300080.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
          <h3>Ursula's Secret</h3>
          <h4>Mairi Wilson</h4>
          <h4>£7.99</h4>
          <div class="read-more"><a href="../ursula-s-secret.html"><button type="button">Read More</button></a></div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably seems like a really daft question, but where should the jQuery go? I've tried putting it in Script tags in the static block (between the jquery call above and the flip-container div, and I've tried putting it in the Head section of my document, but it doesn't seem to be using that code in either instance?

Comment: A. I saw that you alreay have refference to the `jquery` library so you can't (and don't need) to add another refference. B. you need to wrap the code with `$(document).ready` function (not must but better. see -https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and than wrap it with `script` tag and put it in the end of the `body` tag. Let me know if you success.

Comment: Ok - so I need to put '<script type="text/javascript"> $( document).ready(function() { $('flipper').each(function() { var elem = $(this), front = elem.find('.front'); elem.height(front.height()); }); }); </script>' at the bottom of the body section?

Comment: Thanks. By adding the following around the script 'code';(function($){ // REST OF CODE HERE // })(jquery)'code' I've got it to work sometimes. In Chrome (desktop & mobile), Opera, Edge and Firefox I've had it both work and not. In Internet Explorer the sizing works fine, but the '.back' panel does not appear (just a back-to-front version of '.front'). In Safari, the JS does not appear to be working, and a similar issue to Internet Explorer occurs, but you get a brief flash of the '.back' panel before it disappears, and the drop shadow of '.back' is visible at all times. Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: (By sometimes work and not, I mean, sometimes the height will set, and not other times). Most recent code at: http://bit.ly/1Mz2nQ0

Comment: That's because when this script runing the `.flipper`s are hidden, so the browser can't calculate the height of the `.front`. Let's try something: Instead `$(document).ready` change it to `$(window).load`. This make the code run later. Hopefully the `.flipper`s will be shown by then.

Comment: brilliant, that's solved the sizing element. Just need to work out the internet explorer / safari issue, which should hopefully just require me to tweak some of the css (https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip#ieflip) Big thanks for all of your help.